# gdal_polygonize creating empty line file instead of polygon

Tags: python, gdal, polygonize, subprocess

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I suspect it is something simple and a duh moment. I'm just trying to get gdal_polygonize.py to make a polygon shapefile of a raster with a single value. It creates a SHP, but it is an empty line file.

Thoughts?

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr
import os
import subprocess
"""
# Utility function to polygonize a raster with only 1 value
# @param
#     [in_raster] - full path to a GeoTIFF
#     Example: rast = r'C:\Temp\MyRast.tif'
#     [shp] - full path to a shapefile to be created
#     Example: shp = r'C:\Temp\MyShape.shp'
#     [region] - integer indicating which connectedness setting to use
# Example call: polygonize(r'C:\Temp\MyRast.tif', r'C:\Temp\MyShape.shp', 4)
"""
def polygonize (in_raster, shp, region):
    ## Open the raster as a GDAL object
    raster = gdal.Open(in_raster)
    ## Get the projection of the raster
    prj = raster.GetProjection()
    ## Create a spatial reference system object from the projection
    shp_srs = osr.SpatialReference(wkt=prj)
    ## Set the driver for writing the SHP
    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
    ## Specify the output SHP dataset
    out_dataset = driver.CreateDataSource(shp)
    ## Create a layer object for GDAL to write to with the PRJ set the same as input raster
    out_layer = out_dataset.CreateLayer(os.path.basename(shp)[:-4], srs=shp_srs)

    if region == 4:
        ## Create a variable to hold the command syntax for 'gdal_polygonize' operation
        cmd = ['python', r'c:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\gdal_polygonize.py', in_raster, '-f', 'ESRI Shapefile', shp, out_layer, 'DN']
        ## Execute the command using subprocess
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        ## Wait for the process to finish    
        out, err = process.communicate()
        ## Let user know what is happening
        print ("Finished polygonizing: {0}".format(os.path.basename(shp)))
        ## Get error code
        errcode = process.returncode
        ## Print error information if wanted
        #print (out, err)
        ## Return the error code if needed - non-zero is error
        #return errcode
```

Here is an [example input raster](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ROXPS3v0C4UExSNTREUnJKRTA/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: So why would a call to gdal.Polygonize that looks like this result in a shapefile with geometry for all values and the code above only providing geometry where it should?
`gdal.Polygonize( src_band, None, out_layer, -1, [], None )`
Obviously preface this with selecting the band from the raster.
`src_band = raster.GetRasterBand(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Using the QGIS GUI, it works for me with this command line:

```
gdal_polygonize.bat F:/path/to/MyRast/MyRast.tif -f "ESRI Shapefile" G:/test.shp test DN
```

Your codes misses the output field name which defaults to DN in the GUI.

Comment: Thanks Andre, your post made me reevaluate what I was passing. Sloppy work on my part. I had copy/pasted a variable assignment and simply added the new name to the left without deleting the old. So the raster I thought I was passing in wasn't actually a raster. That's the main reason it wasn't doing anything. But it does appear that 'DN' is required in my case for the polygonization to occur, which I'm a little confused about since after adding it my output file name is 'DN.shp'. What's causing that?

Comment: You have still mixed up `out_layer` and `dst_layer`.

Comment: Right, that was a copy/paste issue on the post. I changed variable names. So I'm getting an empty shapefile made that has the name I want and a shapefile named 'DN.shp' that actually has the polygons. Any idea what's going on? I'm not sure I have the command right...

Comment: I don't have much experience with python, but do you tell the driver to create a **polygon** layer anywhere?

Comment: Driver and related shp/layer writing should be handled with this portion:
`## Set the driver for writing the SHP
    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
    ## Specify the output SHP dataset
    out_dataset = driver.CreateDataSource(shp)
    ## Create a layer object for GDAL to write to with the PRJ set the same as input raster
    out_layer = out_dataset.CreateLayer(os.path.basename(shp)[:-4], srs=shp_srs)`

Comment: But to be perfectly honest, I snagged that code from elsewhere and I'm operating under the assumption that it is good. I think there is something weird about the subprocess command versus calling gdal.Polygonize function directly, but I haven't figured out what yet. The subprocess command also does not include the NoData value Zero, but the gdal.Polygonize does; and is significantly slower as a result.